# What do the various A340 configurations (clean, 1, 1+F, etc.) mean?

Tags: airbus-a340

Could anyone describe (or direct to usable documentation) me aircraft configurations? What does it mean clean configuration, configuration 1, 1+F, 2, etc... Is there any section in FCOM's describing it in clear way?

Comment: You don't have to sign your question like an email. We got a link to your user right there at the bottom right ;)

Comment: @zundi - it's a hard thing to get used to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify lever movement direction and actual flap/slat combination, I attached a more detailed snippet from the A340 FCOM § 1.27.50

Note that in-flight selection of 2 above 193.5 kt equals config 1* (same as 1+F but with more slats).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's...quite complicated, especially the 1+F. I always prefer Boeing.

Answer (score 9):

A *clean configuration* is a configuration where landing gear, flaps, slats, spoilers etc. are retracted.

1, 1+F, 2, 3 and FULL refer to the level at which the flaps are currently deployed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clear answer, it helps a lot! Could you clarify, is it taken from fcom (exact chapter) or some other documentation?

Comment: The image comes from the FCOM Aircraft Systems, 27 Flight Controls, 30 Flaps & Slats, 20 Controls & Indications, - Pedestal (source: http://www.pprune.org/tech-log/520309-clarification-a320-qrh-flaps-slat-failure.html)

Comment: Do you remember whether the 1+F position is selected during extension or retraction?